# Can we do ResetRoleInheritance on web but retain item level permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We need to reset web permissions to let it inherit parent web permissions but when we do so our list item permissions start inheriting as well which is a good thing but some items have unique permissions and we want to retain them.

Can we do `web.ResetRoleInheritance` on web but retain item level permissions ?